# Show all customers who havent placed an order in a specific time frame

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

Fairly new to SQL and databases.... I have the following issue...
Database for a shipping company, three relevant tables for this problem are;

Customer (CustomerID, Name, Address etc)

Shipment (ShipmentID, ScheduleName, DepartDate, ArriveDate, DepartPort, ArrivePort)

CustomerOrder (CustomerID, ShipmentID, Fee etc)

I need to show
'All customers that have NOT placed an order within a specific year, i.e. 2019' Im struggling to find the correct query for this. Im working on sample data, there are 8 customers in the database, 3 of which have orders for shipments departing in 2019. Therefore the result im hoping to get is a list of the 5 remaining customers who did not have orders on these shipments.

I can easily show customer who have placed an order and those who have never placed an order however im struggling to show those who haven't placed an order in a specific timeframe.

Any ideas or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT***

Desired Result - Show the 5 customers who havent placed an order where the shipping depart date is in 2019

I have tried;

~
    SELECT CustomerID from customer
    LEFT OUTER JOIN customerorder
    ON Customer.CustomerID = CustomerOrder.CustomerID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN shipment 
    ON CustomerOrder.ShipmentID = Shipment.ShipmentID
    WHERE shipment.DepartDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
    AND CustomerOrder.CustomerID IS NULL
~

However this bring back no results.

The three tables have the following information

Customer - (simply table of customer details) (CustomerID, Name, Address, Tel, Type, Size, RegisteredSince)

Shipment -  (Details each shipment scheduled) (ShipmentID, ScheduleName, DepartDate, DepartPort, ArriveDate, ArrivePort, Season)

CustomerOrder -  (Details customer order, but not individual items on an order) (OrderID, ShipmentID, CustomerID)

Im not sure if its the join thats the problem? There are 4 shipments in 2019 in the sample data with a total of 3 customers. I need to show the customerID's of the 5 customers who didnt place an order within these dates.

Ive tried a few different queries, have been searching online but im new to this and not quite sure where im going wrong. I am able to identify customers who have never placed an order but as soon as I add the date ranges i get no results.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: What have you tried, or what research have you performed and haven't understood? There's a lot out there on how to do such logic. A `LEFT JOIN` is the most common way.

Comment: Thanks have edited question to try to explain better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Desired Result - Show the 5 customers who havent placed an order where the shipping depart date is in 2019

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM Customer c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM CustomerOrder co JOIN 
                       Shipment sh
                       ON co.shipmentID = sh.ShipmentID
                  WHERE c.CustomerID = co.CustomerID AND
                       sh.DepartDate >= '2019-01-01' AND
                       sh.DepartDate < '2020-01-01'
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this seems to have done the trick. To understand this better can you explain what 'SELECT 1' does?

Comment: @LauraRoscoe . . . An `exists` subquery only checks for the existence of *rows*, not particular *values*.  The `1` is the simplest thing to type.  You could use anything.  I would recommend not using `NULL` because I think that is confusing (`NULL` should not mean the presence of a valid value).  Ironically, in some databases, the expression could even generate an error, such as `1 / 0` -- but don't use that either, except to show off to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't now from your relations where do you save the order date, but you could change anything if it is needed. I have used DepartDate to mange orders Year that are different from 2019: 
Example:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN CustomerOrder co ON c.CutomerID = co.CutomerID
INNER JOIN Shipment sh ON co.shipmentID = sh.ShipmentID
WHERE YEAR(sh.DepartDate) <> 2019
```

Get all *cutomers* data where *DepartDate* not equal to *2019*

Comment: Thanks, thats great but unfortunately it wants all customers who havent placed an order in that timeframe. Some of the customers that placed orders within the time frame also placed others outside of it. I just need to show the ones that didnt place orders specifically in that time. For example. Customer number 1 places orders in 2018, 2019 and 2020. Whereas customer 2 places orders in 2018 only. The result would need to show only Customer 2 (who didnt place an order in 2019) but the above query also shows customer 1 (who did)

Comment: from this query that I did you should make another sub-query where you select all customer id that have done order on 2019  and exclude theme,... I have made another post of full query . hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be the solution that you want, here is full-query. 
Sub-Query means you get all customerID-s that made orders on 2019 and we are exclude theme with not in ...

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN CustomerOrder co ON c.CutomerID = co.CutomerID
INNER JOIN Shipment sh ON co.shipmentID = sh.ShipmentID
WHERE YEAR(sh.DepartDate) <> 2019 AND  c.CutomerID 
  NOT IN (SELECT c.* 
          FROM Customer c
          INNER JOIN CustomerOrder co ON c.CutomerID = co.CutomerID
          INNER JOIN Shipment sh ON co.shipmentID = sh.ShipmentID
          WHERE YEAR(sh.DepartDate) = 2019)
```

Comment: I do believe you've cracked it! I had to change the select in the sub query to one column, it wouldnt allow select *  however its certainly given me the correct results! Thank you so much, going to go and read through it and fully understand it now! Thanks again

Comment: @LauraRoscoe . . . I don't think this answers your question correctly.  First, it requires that customers have placed an order -- something not required by your description of the problem.  Second, it can return duplicate rows for customers who have made multiple purchases in other years.  And, it is more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @gordon-linoff I think you are wrong - Here is the requirement: "Customer number 1 places orders in 2018, 2019 and 2020. Whereas customer 2 places orders in 2018 only. The result would need to show only Customer 2 (who didnt place an order in 2019) " which Laura asked for

Comment: Oki doke, so i tested this and added a customer with no orders at all. I ran the query and it didnt show the new customer, so I think gordon is correct as i need to show ALL customers who havent made an order in 2019 (this would include any customers who have never made an order)

Comment: Yes - And that is because of INNER JOIN - which there could be LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN etc, which you should think about it :) , INNER JOIN means what two tables has in common

Answer (score 0):

Just do a left outer join on orders by customerId in the appropriate date range where the customerID doesn't exist:

```
select c.* 
from customers c
    left outer join (
        select customerID 
        from CustomerOrder o 
            join Shipment s on s.ShipmentID=o.ShipmentID 
        where DepartDate>='2020-01-01' and DepartDate<'2021-01-01'
    ) x on x.customerID=c.customerID  
where x.customerid is null
```

The subquery selects every single customerID who ordered in the date range.
The left outer join and "customerid is null" does a negative match on those customers who don't exist in our subquery.